# Command line - delete lines with a particular number of words

Tags: bash

I have a number of text files in a directory, and I would like to delete the ones that have exactly 27143 words (strictly speaking, I would like to save *one* of them, but that's easily done separately). Is the a simple bash one-liner that achives this?

Answer (score 2):

```
wc -w `find . -type f -depth 1` | grep -E "^ +27143 " | cut -b10-
```

...should list the files, you can pass the output to `rm` yourself (I'm not writing the `rm` here to encourage you to *double-check the list of files*). You might need `xargs` instead of the backquotes if there are too many files in the current directory.